# How to include other exe files when packaging JavaFX into an exe?

Tags: java, javafx, exe

Currently, in Intellij, it is possible to package JavaFX into an installation file through artifacts.

How can other installation files be included in the packaging process (such as the MSSQL installation file)?

And through this installation file, other files can be installed during installation.

Currently, only packaging is done on Intellij, and there has been no attempt to package through other software.

Comment: This is likely too complex and open-ended to be well-answered on StackOverflow.  You could look into technology such as [`jpackage`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/jpackage/packaging-overview.html#GUID-C1027043-587D-418D-8188-EF8F44A4C06A) or a commercial packaging and installation tool.  Recommendation of individual tools is outside of scope for StackOverflow.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to know what methods or software can be used to include the MSSQL installation file in the process of converting Java into an exe. Additionally, during the installation process of the exe, MSSQL will be automatically triggered for installation.

Comment: "I want to know what methods or software can be used to include the MSSQL installation file" -> I already provided info on that (you can use jpackage) - read the documentation on it that I linked.  It is not easy or trivial to use (especially given your requirements).  There are other tools, but [software recommendations are out of scope for StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Thank you @jewelsea for your reply. I have been researching how to achieve my goal through jpackage.